# Slope detection with three axis in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-physics

I want to ask that how to move a car on a slope in a game. I am building a game in JavaScript using `THREE.js` API for that. I want to detect the slope, I searched a lot on how to find the slope and found that slope is vertical distance divide by horizontal distance. In `THREE.js` we have two coordinate X and Z, in this situation how we can detect the horizontal distance as vertical distance is the height and in this situation it is Y axis.

Help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the problem from a different angle. Use the normal of the triangle to do your calculations. Actually why dont you move the car so that its normal (the normal of the plane formed by the four wheels) matches the normal of the triangle.